# Lazy load only loads first image

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

need help badly! I'm trying to add a lazy load feature to my project using vanilla javascript but it only loads the first image and other images remain blurred and not loading.

Here is script:

```
// Lazy loading images
const imgTargets = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');

const loadImg = function (entries, observer) {
  const [entry] = entries;

  if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;

  // Replace src with data-src
  entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;

  entry.target.addEventListener('load', function () {
    entry.target.classList.remove('lazy-img');
  });

  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(loadImg, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: '200px',
});

imgTargets.forEach(img => imgObserver.observe(img));
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="popup swiper-slide swiper-slide2 first-non" style="background: transparent;">
        <img class="lazy-img fetures__img" 
        src="assets/theme/images/laz-non-legendary-1.png"
        data-src="assets/theme/images/non-legendary-1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="popup swiper-slide swiper-slide2 first-non" style="background: transparent;">
        <img class="lazy-img fetures__img" 
        src="assets/theme/images/laz-non-legendary-2.png"
        data-src="assets/theme/images/non-legendary-2.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="popup swiper-slide swiper-slide2 first-non" style="background: transparent;">
        <img class="lazy-img fetures__img" 
        src="assets/theme/images/laz-non-legendary-3.png"
        data-src="assets/theme/images/non-legendary-3.png" />
      </div>
```

Here's CSS just for blur effect:

```
.lazy-img {
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image src

```
entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src.replace("w=10&", "w=800&");
```

Control threshold based on need

```
threshold: 0.2
```

Script Code

```
// Lazy loading images
const imgTargets = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');

const loadImg = function (entries, observer) {
  const [entry] = entries;

  if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;

  // Replace src with data-src
  entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src.replace("w=10&", "w=800&");

  entry.target.addEventListener('load', function () {
    entry.target.classList.remove('lazy-img');
  });

  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(loadImg, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.2,
  rootMargin: '200px',
});

imgTargets.forEach(img => imgObserver.observe(img));
```

Comment: Thank you bro it's working fine as hell ;)